# Scala underscore - ERROR: missing parameter type for expanded function

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax

I know there have been quite a few questions on this, but I've created a simple example that I thought should work,but still does not and I'm not sure I understand why

```
val myStrings = new Array[String](3)
// do some string initialization

// this works
myStrings.foreach(println(_))


// ERROR: missing parameter type for expanded function
myStrings.foreach(println(_.toString))
```

Can someone explain why the second statement does not compile?

Comment: Even simpler: `myStrings.foreach (println)`

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It expands to:

```
myStrings.foreach(println(x => x.toString))
```

You want:

```
myStrings.foreach(x => println(x.toString))
```

The placeholder syntax for anonymous functions replaces the smallest possible containing expression with a function.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981732/scala-underscore-use-to-simplify-syntax-of-function-literals http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259006/underscore-in-named-arguments

Comment: Why does `myStrings.foreach(println(_))` automatically include `toString` for the argument to `println`?

Comment: @Kevi Meredith println calls the toString() of whichever object is passed

Comment: The *The placeholder syntax for anonymous functions replaces the smallest possible containing expression with a function.* helped me with the doubts I expressed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589210/scala-underscore-explanation