# Usage of _ in Scala lambdas

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala underscore - ERROR: missing parameter type for expanded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function)

Assume the following code compiles (`people` is a `List[Person]`):

```
people.map(_.address).foreach(println)
```

Why does the following:

```
people.foreach(println(_.address))
```

produce a message

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$4) => x$4.address)
```

This seems to be the case any time a wildcard is nested in a method call.

Is this because compiler tries to expand the code to?:

```
people.foreach(println(x => x.address))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can verify this using this kind of command:

```
echo object Test { (1 to 1).map(println(_.address)) } > test.scala
scalac -Xprint:typer test.scala
```

You'll find this in result:

```
intWrapper(1).to(1).map[B, That](println(((x$1) => x$1.address)))
```