# In Scala 2.10 or higher, how does one supply an "empty" catch block

Tags: scala, try-catch

I haven't been able to find a way to provide an empty (no op) way to complete a catch block in the following Scala code:

```
var autoCloseables: List[AutoCloseable] = List()
... //some code that fills the list with various java.sql.* instances; Connection, Statement, ResultSet
autoCloseables.map(try {_.close} catch {case se: SQLException => NoOp} )
```

I have tried to replace "`NoOp`" with "`()`", "`Unit`", "`None`", "`se.getMessage()`", etc. I continue to receive an error in Eclipse stating various forms of "type mismatch; found :  Unit, required: AutoCloseable => ?".

I have also tried changing the final line to the below, but still receive the same warning as above:

```
autoCloseables.map(try {_.close} catch {case _: Throwable => } )
```

Any specific guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. And, I know about the ARM library. For now, please assume I am unable to use it and need a resolution framed from this particular problem formation.  Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible the error was triggered by use of `map` instead of `foreach`?  That is, `map` was struggling to find the member type for the new list.

Comment: When I changed it to foreach, the error remained. That does not make your speculation incorrect. It's just that foreach had the same problem as map. Blake's answer, completely obvious after seeing it, was just what I needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import scala.util.Try

autoCloseables.map(a => Try(a.close))
```

Comment: Very nice. Tyvm! So, why is the "a =>" required instead of the underscore syntax? I tried using the underscore syntax and I receive an error: "missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$8) => x$8.close)"

Comment: Meh, I keep thinking you can use `Nothing` in Scala as you can use `_` (bottom) in Haskell. However, in Scala `Nothing` is a type without any instances, so you can't return it.

Comment: Why use `map()` instead of `foreach()`? There's no return value to want.

Comment: @WeaponsGrade Try returns Success(T) or Failure(T). This can optionally be used to handle exceptions or to perform an action if the computation has succeeded.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function