# Uses of _ in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and was trying to understand where we can use underscore and where Scala prevents the use of underscore. I read through various posts but I am not able to completely understand the concept. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Code:

```
object ScalaMainObj {
 def main(args : Array[String])
 {
    val t1 = List(1,2,3,4)
    //t1.foreach(println(_*2))  -> Will refer to this as Line1 
    //t1.foreach(_*2)           -> Will refer to this as Line2    
    t1.foreach(x => println(x*2)) //-> Will refer to this as Line3
 }
```

Question:
I am trying to understand why code in Line1 gives me an error while compiling. The error I get is "missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) ⇒ x$1.$times(2))"
Does the above statement indicate that scala is not able to resolve the return type of (x$1 * 2) function?

Since the code in Line2 is compiling, I believe that scala is able to resolve the type of '_'as Int. (Tried to replace * function with / function since "/" function is available to Int and not Strings)

Thanks again for any suggestions/explanations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala underscore - ERROR: missing parameter type for expanded function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function)

Comment: Because Line1 would expand to `t1.foreach(println(x =>x*2))`

Comment: Have a quick follow up question: Why doesn't "t1.foreach(println(_))" statement get translated to t1.foreach(println(x -> x)) and fail.. I am trying to understand these basic concepts in detail.. Thanks again for the help

Comment: It translates to `t1.foreach(x => println(x))` because it replaces the smallest possible expression. Think like this: it expands to `x => expression_that_uses_x`. What uses x? Function `println` does (it uses it as a parameter). Expanding to `println(x => x)` makes no sense. For a small exercise - what do you think `t1.foreach(println(_.toString))` expands to?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Below is my understanding: t1.foreach(println(_.toString)) will be translated to t1.foreach(println(x=>x.toString)) since x.toString is the closest expression   Also in case of t1.foreach(println(_*2)) it gets translated to foreach(println(x => x*2)) since x*2 is the closest expression.. Please correct me if I am misinterpreting the concept

Comment: In REPL try to use `// show` magic comment and you will see what Scala is trying to do.