# scala foreach with one augment, cannot take any operation?

Tags: scala, foreach

I'm new to Scala, and find 'foreach' a little confused, like :

```
    (1 to 10).foreach(println(_)) //OK
    (1 to 10).foreach(x=>println(x+1)) //OK
    (1 to 10).foreach(println(_+1)) //ERROR
```

I'd know what's up in the 3rd code line. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala underscore - ERROR: missing parameter type for expanded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(1 to 10).foreach(println(_+1))
```

comiler see the above expression as:

```
(1 to 10).foreach(println(x => x + 1))
```

And you want it like this:

```
(1 to 10).foreach(x=>println(x+1))
```

The placeholder syntax for anonymous functions replaces the smallest possible containing expression with a function.

Comment: @LuoJing if it solves the problem please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use _ for this parsing precedes type checking, so there's really no way for the compiler to read your mind here and guess what you intended
consider writing the below code it's cleaner code anyway because it keeps computation separate from I/O.

`(1 to 10).map(_ + 1).foreach(println)`